# pythonのrangeについて

Tags: python, python3

下記のようなリストをrangeで１行でどのように作ればよいのでしょうか？
`[98, 99, 1, 2, 3]`

`[i for i in range(98, 3)]`だと空のリストになってしまいます。
`[98, 99]`と`[1,2,3]`をそれぞれ作ってマージすれば作れることはわかっているのですが、上記のようにリスト内包表記で１行で書けないでしょうか。

Comment: `[i % 100 for i in range(98, 104) if i != 100]` というのはどうでしょう。

Comment: それと、こちら [Circular Range in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40970290/circular-range-in-python) が参考になるかと思います(`0` が含まれますが)。

Comment: リスト`[98, 99, 1, 2, 3]`をそのまま使っても良いと思いますが、`range`を使いたい理由を説明した方が良いかも。1～99の間で循環させたいとか。

Comment: rangeを使って１～９９の間で循環させる方法を知りたいと思い質問させていただきました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> rangeを使って１～９９の間で循環させる方法

数学的には「99で割った剰余 + 1」で表現できます。

```
start = 98
num = 5
li = [1 + ((n - 1) % 99) for n in range(start, start + num)]
# li == [98, 99, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

内包表記1つだと厳しい気がします。
内包表記2つ使えばなんとかいけるかと思います。

```
 new_list = [i for i in range(98,100)] + [i for i in range(1,4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### イテレーション可能な物の結合

例えばchamponさんの回答のように、`range` を繋げるには、一度リストにして `+` する以外に、[itertools.chain](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/itertools.html?#itertools.chain) を使う方法もあります。

```
[i for i in itertools.chain(range(98, 99+1), range(1, 3+1))]
```

より汎用的には、例えば [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/itertools.html?#itertools.islice)や[itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/itertools.html?#itertools.cycle)と組み合わせ、

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import itertools

start = 98
end = 3
max_num = 99

# 必要な要素数: 今回は最終値(end)などから求め、5個になる
num = end - start + 1 + (end < start and max_num)

result = [i for i in itertools.islice(
    itertools.chain(
        range(start, max_num + 1),
        itertools.cycle(range(1, max_num + 1))
    ),
    num,
)]
# result は [98, 99, 1, 2, 3]
```

のように書けます。`[i for i in foo_bar]` は `list(foo_bar)` でもよいです。内包表記ではなくなってしまいますが。